# Variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have two questions about this:

1. I am trying to assign an image to a variable img1 and then insert that variable img1 into the CSS, but it's not working.  What am I doing wrong in the code below?  (Note, the code works fine if I don't use a variable i.e. if I put the image path directly into it, so I know there must be a problem with the variable)
2. Assuming that I can get the img1 variable to work, can I somehow turn it into an id or class so that I can manipulate it with jQuery? For example, I would like to be able to do **$("img1").hide(1000)** in the same way I do it with the class .contactform in the code below.

   ```
   var img1 = url('/wp-content/themes/custom/images/blah.jpg') repeat;

   $("#submit").click(function(){
       $(".contactform").hide(1000,function(){
           $(".contactforms").css({display:"block"});
           $("body.custom").css({background: "img1"});

       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not valid Javascript syntax. You need to wrap your img1 in quotes so it's recognized as a string. Try this:

```
var img1 = "url('/wp-content/themes/custom/images/blah.jpg') repeat";

$("#submit").click(function(){
    $(".contactform").hide(1000,function(){
        $(".contactforms").css({display:"block"});
        $("body.custom").css({background: img1});

    });
  });
```

Comment: thank you.  Are you able to help out with the second question?

Comment: For example, I would like to be able to do $("img1").hide(1000) in the same way I do it with the class .contactform in the code below.

Comment: You can't use it like that -- it's part of a CSS style, not a DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

$("body.custom").css({background: "img1"}); should be
$("body.custom").css({background: img1});

"img1" is a literal string for the characters "img1" whereas img1 is a variable identifier.

Comment: thank you.  Are you able to help out with the second question?

Comment: For example, after the variable is set, I would like to be able to do $("img1").hide(1000) in the same way I do it with the class .contactform in the code below.

Comment: As the image is a css property and not actually within the page document, you cannot manipulate it with jQuery the same way you can for elements of in the DOM. One way to attempt this might be to insert an image element in the body, float it so it doesn't interfere with layout (really depends on your layout and css), with a z-index set to -1 (or any negative number). Then  you can add effects to the image and do what you want.

Comment: o.k, thanks. A few people answered so I flipped a coin to see who gets accepted answer, and you unfortunately lost. but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try saying:

```
var img1 = "url('/wp-content/themes/custom/images/blah.jpg') repeat;";
```

With the quotes. Your JS engine should have complained. Always check the error console!

For Part 2, you could write a little helper:

```
function setImage(img) {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    $(".contactform").hide(1000,function() {
        $(".contactforms").css({display:"block"});
        $("body.custom").css({background: img});
    });
  });
}
```

Originally you'd say `setImage(img1)`, but you can later call it again with different parameters. If you only need to change the filename, perhaps something like this:

```
function setImageFilename(filename) {
  setImage("url('/wp-content/themes/custom/images/" + filename + "') repeat;");
}
```

Comment: thank you.  Are you able to help out with the second question?

Comment: I don't think I was clear about what I was trying to do in the second question, because your answer seems a bit off. For example, I want to be able to do something like  "img1.hide(1000, function ..." in the same way that code does it with the class  "(.contactform").hide(1000, function.... " how can I do that?

Comment: @mjmitche: Oh, I see -- well, you can just store the target object and the callback function somewhere and then say `myobj.hide(1000, myfun);`. E.g. say `var myobj = $(".contactform");` or something, though  I don't quite follow what you're hiding where and when.